# Error # 1045 - Cannot Log in to MySQL server -> phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, vps, password

We have installed PHPMyAdmin on a windows machine running IIS 7.0.
We are able to connect to MySQL using command-line, But we are not able to connect using PHPMyAdmin.
The error displayed is: `Error #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.`
Can somebody please help?

`PHP Version 5.4.0`
`mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Revision: 323634 $`
`phpMyAdmin-3.5.4-rc1-all-languages.7z`

**EDIT :**
I followed the link below with no success, mean i changed that password but phpmyadmin still has that error...
[C.5.4.1.1. Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Thanks.

Comment: is any body home?

Answer (score 1):

Try te following:

1) Login to MySQL server using your console

2) `update mysql.user set PASSWORD=PASSWORD('newpassword') where User='root';`

3) `flush privileges;`

4) `service mysql restart`

See if you can access your databases using phpmyadmin. It would be nice if you did provide more information.

Comment: thanks for the answer... i do that, but that error is still out there!

Comment: i edit my question!

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/446764/cant-login-in-phpmyadmin-and-mysql-after-fresh-installation-of-lamp-server-and  Maybe it helps

Comment: thanks for the link -> no help -> i still have that error.